# Differential equation involving the Dirac delta

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dirac-delta

I have been trying to figure this out for a while, and I was wondering if anyone had any ideas. I need to solve the following differential equation:

$m\frac{d^2 r}{dt^2}=\epsilon\delta'(r)$,

where $\delta(r)$ is the Dirac delta function, and $m,\epsilon$ are constants. What would be the best way to go about this?

Cheers

Comment: $\delta'(r) = -r'(0)$, no?

Comment: Ok, I probably should have given some context. r here is referring to the relative position of two particles moving on the real line. $\delta(r)$ is the potential. This is an Euler-Lagrange equation.
I can sort of see how your argument works. Are you calling $r$ here a test function?

Comment: $r$ is a function of $t$, and $\delta(r)$ is dependent on $r$

Comment: What does $\delta(r)$ is the potential mean? For me, $\delta(r)$ is a *real number* - $\delta'$ is a linear functional from some space of (test) functions to $\mathbb{R}$, and since $r$ is a function (and we assume it's in whatever domain $\delta'$ has), the result of applying $\delta'$ to $r$ is a real number. Though maybe I'm missing something - I'm not a physicist...

Comment: The usual definition for the derivative of a distribution $\Lambda$ is that $\Lambda'(f) = - \Lambda(f')$, from which it would follows that $\delta'(r) = -\delta(r') = -r'(0)$ (since $\delta(f) = f(0)$). But again, maybe I'm missing something...

Comment: Thanks, this works exactly how I need it to!

Comment: Good! Btw, be carefull about calling $r$ a test function here - test functions are usually expected to be $C^\infty$, and to decay quickly - not sure if your solution $r$ satisfies that. What you're using here is that $\delta'$ is a very well-behaved distribution, and you can thus define it on a much larger domain than what you get for e.g. general tempered distributions.

Answer (score 0):

My approach is based on two facts:

1. $\delta $ is the distribitional derivative of the Heaviside function $H = \chi_{[0,\infty)}$.
2. A distribution  whose first derivative is identically $0$ is constant.

Thus, $mr'=\epsilon \delta +C = \epsilon H'+C$. By the same logic, $mr = \epsilon H  +Ct+B$.

Answer (score -1):

I have tried a little can't sure correct or not,
$$m\frac{d^2r}{dt^2}=\epsilon\delta'(r)$$
$$\frac{d}{dt}\left[ m\frac{dr}{dt} -\epsilon\delta \right]=0$$
$$\left[m\frac{dr}{dt} -\epsilon\delta \right]=C$$
$$\int dr-\frac{\epsilon}{m}\int\delta\,dr =\int C\, dt$$
$$r-\frac{\epsilon}{m}=Ct + C'$$

Comment: You have integrated $\delta$ from $-\infty$ to $\infty$ instead of taking the primitive function of it. Also, the integral should be w.r.t. $t$, not $r$.